# Parse4j with strange character

Tags: java, parsing, encoding

QUESTION UPDATED

I am using Parse and Parse4J (https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) for my project and I get this strange bahavior. I have this sentence in online database ( I am using Excel parser to upload question but I dont think that it is inportant in this case becasuse upload is OK and question seems normal on the internet - parse web interface) I see this :

```
 Somebody who is boastful can be described as a ….?
```

for upload I using

```
 put("Question", question);
 System.out.println(question);
```

and I get the same result which is above (correct form)

At the end is tripple dots and on the parse it seems normal but if I use getString() - clasical way on this question I get

```
 public String getQuestion(){
    String question = getString("Question");
    System.out.println(question);
    return question;
}
```

I get

```
Somebody who is boastful can be described as a â€¦.?
```

It is interesting that I dont get this on Android (where I am using almost the same code )

Is there anyway to get rid of it ( set up this encoding or erase it from parse ? ) Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you're using - and explain how you're observing the result. (On a console? In a web app? In the debugger?)

Comment: UPDATED question added code and better formulation of problem - hope it help to understand

Answer (score 0):

I try this code :

```
try {
   row.createCell(id_cell++).setCellValue(new String(q.getQuestion().getBytes(),"UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and output was correct, so I assume that it was because of bad default encoding (maybe Windows-1250)